# Getting unique values from a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large DataFrame (20 million rows). One of the columns (called category) has values like this:

> food::restaurant::cafe::business
>
> car dealer::business::automotive
>
> barber::business

I want to get all unique values in this column into a list/set.  What is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Say `df` is your DataFrame and the column in question is `category`:

You can first get a 1d NumPy array of categories, then call `set()` constructor on it:

```
set(df.category.str.split('::', expand=True).values.flatten())
```

Example:

```
print(df)

                           category
0  food::restaurant::cafe::business
1  car dealer::business::automotive
2                  barber::business

res = set(df.category.str.split('::', expand=True).values.flatten())

{'barber',
 'automotive',
 'car dealer',
 'restaurant',
 None,
 'cafe',
 'food',
 'business'}
```

To get rid of `None`:

```
res = df.category.str.split('::', expand=True).values.flatten()
res = set(filter(lambda x: x is not None, res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack()` and `unique()`:

```
df.x.str.split("::", expand=True).stack().unique()
```

**Note** Speed tests show Brad Solomon's answer is faster, see bottom of this answer.  I'll keep my solution as it demonstrates a solution using only Pandas method-chaining, but if it's speed you want, moving to Numpy via `values` and then `set()` seems best.

With sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([["food::restaurant::cafe::business"],
                   ["car dealer::business::automotive"],
                   ["barber::business"]], columns=['x'])  

df.x.str.split("::", expand=True).stack().unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['food', 'restaurant', 'cafe', 'business', 'car dealer',
       'automotive', 'barber'], dtype=object)
```

Benchmarking against Brad Solomon's answer:

```
%%timeit
df.x.str.split("::", expand=True).stack().unique()
# 737 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
res = df.x.str.split('::', expand=True).values.flatten()
set(filter(lambda x: x is not None, res))
# 461 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```